# Mongoose query findOne({params}) returns null, even though it succeeds in mongo shell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here are the software versions in use:

- mongoose 4.10.8,
- mongodb 3.4,
- express 4.13.4,
- nodejs 6.11.1,
- npm 3.10.10,

In Mongo shell I can findOne my user without a problem:

```
> db.users.findOne({"admin":"true"}).pretty()

>{
        "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-15T06:08:24.742Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-03T03:11:23.653Z"),
        "salt" : "...",
        "hash" : "...",
        "username" : "Testuser",
        "notifications" : [
                {
                }
        ],
        "lastname" : "Administrator",
        "firstname" : "Webmaster",
        //********* FIELD I AM SEARCHING FOR HERE!
        "admin" : "true",
        "companyName" : "",
        "__v" : 11,
        "company" : ObjectId("59868130522b9a0fe05808c7")
}
>
```

Within one of my routers, I try and grab this user:

```
>Users.findOne({"admin":"true"}, "username", function (err, admin) { do stuff here});
```

Referencing http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

I've tried all possible variations of the query. From removing the quotes to just {admin:true}, to using just find({admin:true}) instead of findOne .. but no matter what I try, it refuses to return anything but null. I've tried doing it as a query and calling exec instead of passing a callback function.

In a different use, I do Users.findById and get the result no problem. So I know it's not an issue accessing the db or a problem with the schema. I've even used findOne with no search parameters and am able to find my user (it's the first in the DB). I'm going insane. Does anyone have any suggestions? I just don't know what else I could possibly try....

user.js schema for reference..

```
var mongoose                = require('mongoose');
var Schema                  = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose   = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var Notification = new Schema({
    body: {type: String, default: ''}
}, {timestamps:true});


var User = new Schema({

    //Is this user an admin? 
    admin: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    firstname: { type: String, default: ''},
    lastname: { type: String, default: ''},
    //Array of all the notifications for this user
    notifications: [Notification]

}, {timestamps: true});


User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Comment: `admin: {type: Boolean, default: false},` is actually incorrect for the stored data. The data is actually stored as a "string". So either fix your data or correct your schema to be `admin: String` instead. Mongoose is coercing the "string" supplied in the query to `boolean` and that of course does not actually match the data in the collection.

Comment: I have so many conflicting emotions right now. Bless your heart Neil. This was indeed the problem, and of course it was self inflicted. I had manually set that field as "true" from the mongodb shell...not having a full conscious understanding of the different types of variables you can store within mongo. I just sort of foolishly overlooked it and considered it to be a formatting deal. Anyway. Wow, you are a hero to one more random internetter. Thank you again very much for replying. Now to figure out how to mark this as the correct answer....

Comment: @user6641203: You need to prompt neil to add his comment as an answer so you can mark it as accepted. If he doesn't do that in a reasonable timeframe I'd add it as an answer yourself and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Answer, provided by [Neil Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn) ... the data that was actually stored in my database is {"admin":"true"} ... where the admin field is a string value. Now, in my mongoose schema, I have that field set as a boolean, so when I go to find({"admin":"true"}) it will automatically convert that "true" string value into a true boolean value, thus never finding a match because "true" != true. This problem happened because I had manually set that field to "true" using the mongodb shell; so I could create an admin user. Mongoose by default per my schema, sets that value to false.